# Prevent tab-siwtch on p:tabView when form validation fails

Tags: forms, validation, primefaces

I'm using a tabView-Element of primefaces. The first tab points to the "Home" element the second one to a registration form. The registration form is validated. The problem is, when the form is validated the user is redirect to the home tab. When the user navigates back, he can see the validation errors.

This seems to be a more or less common problem, but I did not find a proper solution. I tried out Oleg Varaksin [suggestion](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.de/2013/02/how-to-prevent-tab-changing-in.html?showComment=1369987144645#c2363045645571844425) to prevent a user switching tabs when a form validation failed, but my problem starts earlier.

I tried to fiddle aorund with the onTabChange event but with no success. Is there a mistake in my code or how can I approach may probelm? I would welcome a push in the right direction.

```
<p:tabView id="mainTabView">
    <p:tab title="Startseite" id="startPage">
        <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:400px;border:none !important"
            id="layout_login">
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="305">
                <p:panel>
                    <h:form id="loginForm">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="gridWithNoBorders reducedFontSize">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Benutzername:" />
                            <p:inputText size="14" value="#{data.username}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Passwort:" />
                            <p:inputText size="14" value="#{data.loginPassword}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:separator />
                        <h:commandButton styleClass="reducedFontSize" value="Anmelden" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:panel>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:panel>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet(...)
                </p:panel>

                        </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="registrationPage" title="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/tabTitleRegistration')}" >

        <h:form id="registrationForm">
            <p:panel header="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/panelHeaderRegistration')}">
                <p:panelGrid columns="3">

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelEmail')}" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{data.email}" id="email1" required="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/enterEmailAddress')}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator" />
                        <f:validator validatorId="EmailCompareValidator" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message for="email1" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelRepeatEmail')}" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{data.emailConfirm}" id="email2" required="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/repeatMailAddress')}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message for="email2"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelPrename')}" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{data.prename}" id="prename" required="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/enterPrename')}"/>
                    <p:message for="prename"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelSurname')}" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{data.surname}" id="surname" required="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/enterSurname')}"/>
                    <p:message for="surname"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelPassword')}" />
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{data.registrationPassword}" match="pwd2"
                        required="true" feedback="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/enterPassword')}"
                        weakLabel="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/passwordWeak')}"
                        goodLabel="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/passwordMedium')}"
                        strongLabel="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/passwordStrong')}" />
                    <p:message for="pwd1"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/labelRepeatPassword')}" />
                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{data.confirmPassword}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/repeatPassword')}"/>
                    <p:message for="pwd2"/>

                    <h:commandButton value="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/finishRegistration')}"  actionListener="#{logic.startRegistration}" >
                        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{logic.startRegistration}"/> 
                    </h:commandButton>

                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to combine the `binding` and `ajax` to achieve my goal. It seems that the activeIndex is resetted after the form validation (?) therefore it is not honored after submitting the form. I've used the approach that was suggested by Steves to [use the binding property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10551763/1145597). So here is the working code:

xhtml:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <p:tabView id="mainTabView" binding="#{tabIndexHelper.messagesTab}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabIndexHelper.onTabChange}" />
        <p:tab title="Startseite" id="startPage">
            <ui:include src="HomePage.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="registrationPage" title="#{ivy.cms.co('/Translations/Registration/tabTitleRegistration')}" >
            <ui:include src="RegisterPage.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

And the backing bean:

```
private TabView messagesTab = new TabView();

    public TabView getMessagesTab () {
        return messagesTab;
    }

    public void setMessagesTab(TabView messagesTab ) {
        this.messagesTab = messagesTab;
    }

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {   
        TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getComponent();

        int activeIndex = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab()); 

        this.messagesTab.setActiveIndex(activeIndex);

    }
```

Thanks for support. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the current tab selected if you don't the update or validation should reset the tabview with default tab selected(the first one).

So you could use activeIndex attribut from tabView :

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="#{bean.activeIndex}"/>
```

From [Primeface User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf):

activeIndex is an Integer with default value 0. Index of the active tab.

And create an event for set this var like that :

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped pushing me in the right direction. The problem here is, that the activeIndex seems to be resetted after form validation.

Comment: Your tabView doesn't have activeIndex attribute yet so how can be reset if this is not implement ?

Comment: I set the attribute to test this - no success on that point. I had to use binding. See my post.

Comment: There are several way to do. As long as you get what you want.